# Symfony2 problems with assets

Tags: symfony, assetic

I recently began to add new features on a website that uses Symfony2.
After creating a new bundle that is very similar to the others already working, I created a button to access to the feature.

But then I got the following errors in my browser's developer tool:

```
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//calino-main-colors.css            prod.project.local/:35
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//main-colors.css                   prod.project.local/:28
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//bootstrap-override-colors.css     prod.project.local/:27
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//buttons-colors.css                prod.project.local/:29
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//menus-colors.css                  prod.project.local/:33
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//forms-colors.css                  prod.project.local/:32
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//content-colors.css                prod.project.local/:30
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//mag-colors.css                    prod.project.local/:31
GET prod.project.local/bundles/calinobase/css//search-colors.css                 prod.project.local/:34
```

Plus an error 500 on my page.

After some researches I found that it came from the stylesheets.html.twig file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/bootstrap-override-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/main-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/buttons-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/content-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/mag-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/forms-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/menus-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/search-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/calinobase/css/' ~ colorTheme ~ '/calino-main-colors.css') }}" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Apparently it doesn't find the colorTheme, which is set in the layout.html.twig when it uses the stylesheet:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
            {{ include('::stylesheets.html.twig', {colorTheme: app.user.color|default('bfc100')}, with_context = false) }}
{% endblock %}
```

In my logs I have the following errors:

```
[2015-01-21 15:22:42] request.INFO: Matched route "calinobase_homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "Calino\BaseBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "calinobase_homepage") [] []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException: "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT a0_.id AS id0, a0_.creaDate AS creaDate1, a0_.editDate AS editDate2, a0_.title AS title3, a0_.slug AS slug4, a0_.intro AS intro5, a0_.content AS content6, a0_.alaune AS alaune7, a0_.published AS published8, a0_.thread_id AS thread_id9, a0_.articleTheme_id AS articleTheme_id10, a0_.avatar_id AS avatar_id11 FROM article_mag a0_ WHERE a0_.alaune = 1 ORDER BY a0_.creaDate DESC LIMIT 1':  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'calinofriendsdb.article_mag' doesn't exist" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 53 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\TableNotFoundException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT a0_.id AS id0, a0_.creaDate AS creaDate1, a0_.editDate AS editDate2, a0_.title AS title3, a0_.slug AS slug4, a0_.intro AS intro5, a0_.content AS content6, a0_.alaune AS alaune7, a0_.published AS published8, a0_.thread_id AS thread_id9, a0_.articleTheme_id AS articleTheme_id10, a0_.avatar_id AS avatar_id11 FROM article_mag a0_ WHERE a0_.alaune = 1 ORDER BY a0_.creaDate DESC LIMIT 1':\n\nSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'calinofriendsdb.article_mag' doesn't exist at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:53, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'calinofriendsdb.article_mag' doesn't exist at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:106, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'calinofriendsdb.article_mag' doesn't exist at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:104)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//forms-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//forms-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//main-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//main-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//bootstrap-override-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//bootstrap-override-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//content-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//content-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//buttons-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//buttons-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:43] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//mag-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//mag-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:44] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//search-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//search-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:44] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//calino-main-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//calino-main-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
[2015-01-21 15:22:44] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/calinobase/css//menus-colors.css" (from "http://prod.project.local/")" at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 3098 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /bundles/calinobase/css//menus-colors.css\" (from \"http://prod.project.local/\") at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/classes.php:3098, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/prod.project.local/htdocs/current/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1498)"} []
```

I develop with PhpStorm so when I mouseover "calinobase" in my stylesheets.html.twig, it displays "Missing assets" so I tried to use *php app/console assets:install --verbose* but I got:

```
Installing assets as hard copies.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
 
 
                                                                              
  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                      
  Failed to remove file "web/bundles/framework/images/blue_picto_more.gif". 
                                                                              
 
 
Exception trace:
 () at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:173
 Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->remove() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:160
 Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->remove() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:160
 Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->remove() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/AssetsInstallCommand.php:98
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\AssetsInstallCommand->execute() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:253
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:882
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:96
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/kemps/dev2/calinofriends/app/console:22
 
 
assets:install [--symlink] [--relative] [target]
```

Not knowing what to do to handle thoses errors, I will be glad to have any  help. Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me.

EDIT: my Symfony project is on a virtual machine installed with Vagrant, configured with Puppetmaster and it has NFS shared folders

Comment: i think you have multiple errors, starting with "table calinofriendsdb.article_mag' doesn't exist", then you seem to have wrong permissions on your web-directory, to pass the colorTheme variable try to use "with" http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html , also after successfull assets:install you have to call assetic:dump to dump the files to the web dir

Comment: @johnSmith I fixed the problem with the table but not with the permissions, as I commented on user3531149's response. I tried to switch the include line to "{% include '::stylesheets.html.twig' with {colorTheme: app.user.color|default('bfc100')} %}" but it didn't changed  a thing. So, did I do something wrong or could you be more specific with the use of "with" in the include please?

Answer (score 0):

Failed to remove file "web/bundles/framework/images/blue_picto_more.gif".

there is something wrong with your permissions, 
if the blue_picto_more.gif was uploaded from the website that means the permissions are set to the webserver account.
usually "nginx or www-data".

if you are only using this site locally or your development server you can just set the web folder to 777 (don't do this on production though).

use this on the command line:

```
chmod -R 777 /pathto/web
```

this one is production-friendly:
 change the permissions to the account you're logging into from the console

```
chown -R the_user web
```

Comment: I have re-tried to "chmod -R 777" my web folder logged as www-data but I get "chmod: changing permissions of `web/bundles/google/js/gdash-1.0.js': Operation not permitted" for example, even using sudo. Moreover, I have the same issue if I try to chown my directory to www-data.

Comment: maybe your account is not on the sudoers list, type "su" enter your root password and try to change the permission again

Comment: no you should change the owner to the account you're using the console with not root, but your regular account

Comment: I think I didn't get what you were trying to make me do. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Not it doesn't, unfortunately. But, does it matter if I typed "sudo su" instead of just "su" because I don't have the password (even blank) on this virtual machine. I access it via vagrant up, and it only asks my host's password.

Comment: if you don't have your superuser password then you also don't have the rights to add your current account to the "sudoers" list, which is required in order to use "sudo" with your current account

Comment: Thing i didn't mentioned: I run this on a VM which has NFS shared folders, so I could change the permissions from my web folder via my host with a simple "sudo chmod -R 777 pathto/web", but thanks for your help.